# Помогите довести до ума for

Tags: php, массивы

Суть такая, извлекаю из бд многомерный массив далее проверяю на присутствие $users['tt'] **!in_array($i, $users)**, если есть такой id ($users['tt']) то вставляю данные если нету вставлю другой блок class="number" с текущей цифрой $i
Ps.Извиняюсь за корявое описание.

```
//Массив взят через print_r
    $count_div = 50; //Сколько должно быть 50 блоков (Данные тоже берутся из бд)
    $users = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [gid] => 36 [tt] => 7 [user] => 2 [wr] => 0 [timestamp] => 0 [login] => demo [email] => demo@demo.dd ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [gid] => 36 [tt] => 2 [user] => 3 [wr] => 0 [timestamp] => 0 [login] => demo1 [email] => demo@no.mail ) )

            for( $i = 1; $i <= $count_div; ++$i ) {
            if( !in_array($i, $users) ){
                $users[] = $i;
                echo '<div class="box"><div class="number">'.$i.'</div></div>';
            }else{
                echo '<div id="'.$user['tt'].'" class="box"><img src="'.$user['email'].'.jpg" alt="User '.$user['user'].'"></div>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: И что здесь не так?

Comment: `in_array` не сработает, потому что в $users только массивы, без значений. А со вложенными массивами не функция не работает. Функция поиска для вложенных массивов - тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, знач буду копать в ту сторону)

Comment: @Andrei Andrei, Попробуйте воспользоваться функцией `array_filter`.

Answer (score -1):

```
$count_div = 50; //Сколько должно быть 50 блоков (Данные тоже берутся из бд)
$users = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [gid] => 36 [tt] => 7 [user] => 2 [wr] => 0 [timestamp] => 0 [login] => demo [email] => demo@demo.dd ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [gid] => 36 [tt] => 2 [user] => 3 [wr] => 0 [timestamp] => 0 [login] => demo1 [email] => demo@no.mail ) )

        for( $i = 1; $i <= $count_div; ++$i ) {
        if( !in_array_r($i, $users) ){
            $users[] = $i;
            echo '<div class="box"><div class="number">'.$i.'</div></div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div id="'.$user['tt'].'" class="box"><img src="'.$user['email'].'.jpg" alt="User '.$user['user'].'"></div>';
        }
    }

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```